# Oracle varchar2 to nvarchar2 conversion

Tags: oracle, character-encoding, varchar2

If I change an existing column type from varchar2 to nvarchar2 in Oracle will Oracle automatically convert existing column data between character set or should I do it myself?

I'm using Oracle 11g, the varchar2 character set is WE8MSWIN1252 and the nvarchar2 character set is AL16UTF16

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the package DBMS_REDEFINITION for doing the changing the varchar2 to nvarchar2 column for a table

Please find the below link which might be helpful

[Using Online Table Redefinition to Migrate a Large Table to Unicode](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch11charsetmig.htm#i1006270)

Also find the documentation for General Character set Migration

[General Character set Migration](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch11charsetmig.htm)